# How do I change the row names of multiple data frames in a list in R at once?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, apply, r-rownames

I have the following example *list* of data.frames:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1:10)
list1 <- list(df[1:3,],df[4:6,],df[7:10,])

[[1]]
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  A B
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6

[[3]]
    A  B
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

How do I change the row names of each data.frame (i.e., each element) of this list at the same time?

For this simple example, how would I change the row name of each row to be a sequential list of numbers starting from 1 for each data.frame in the list?

Desired output:

```
    [[1]]
      A B
    1 1 1
    2 2 2
    3 3 3
    
    [[2]]
      A B
    1 4 4
    2 5 5
    3 6 6
    
    [[3]]
        A  B
    1   7  7
    2   8  8
    3   9  9
    4  10 10
```

I can essentially accomplish creating an object with these row names :

```
lapply(list1,function(x){rownames(x) <- 1:dim(x)[1]})

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

But I cannot figure out how to actually *apply* these row names to either my previously saved object or a new object with desired row names.

Comment: ```lapply(list1, function(x) {row.names(x) <- 1:nrow(x); x})```

Answer (score 3):

Try `` `row.names<-`(..., NULL) ``

```
> lapply(list1, `row.names<-`, NULL)
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  A B
1 4 4
2 5 5
3 6 6

[[3]]
   A  B
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4 10 10
```

or

```
> Map(`row.names<-`, list1, list(NULL))
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  A B
1 4 4
2 5 5
3 6 6

[[3]]
   A  B
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4 10 10
```

Comment: Neat little "shorthand" trick for the simplified sequential example! Very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by setting the `rownames` to `1:nrow(df)` or better `seq_len(nrow(df))`. You almost did it with your solution. You just needed to return the dataframes in your loop instead of the `rownames`.

```r
lapply(list1, function(x) {rownames(x) <- seq_len(nrow(x)); x})
#> [[1]]
#>   A B
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   A B
#> 1 4 4
#> 2 5 5
#> 3 6 6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    A  B
#> 1  7  7
#> 2  8  8
#> 3  9  9
#> 4 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `row.name` argument in `data.frame` function:

```
lapply(list1, data.frame, row.names = NULL)
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  A B
1 4 4
2 5 5
3 6 6

[[3]]
   A  B
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4 10 10
```